# How do i run app in bat nonblocking?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

Lets say i want to do

```
gcc a.cpp
```

BUT i dont want to block. I just want to run and continue, like running in the background. How do i do that in a bat file? I'm using windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
start /b gcc a.cpp
```

this starts the command "without opening a new window" .. which is essentially running the app in the "background". see `start /?` for more options.